# Change query string to allow for multiple values

Tags: html, django, jquery-select2

I have an issue with my query string, the problem is when multiple values are selected my Django search breaks. I get this in the URL `?Query=value1&Query=Value2`. In this scenario, it's only the last value that is searched. What I want to happen is that both values are searched (with the equivalent of an `AND` operator in-between).

This is the desired result `?Query=value1+Value2`.

I've added my search form that uses Select2 and my Django search view below. If you need anything else let me now.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Search form on the front end**

```
<form id="makeitso" role="search" action="" method="get">                   
            <select class="js-example-placeholder-multiple" name="query" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="Value 1">Value 1</option>   
                <option value="Value 2">Value 2</option>   
                <option value="Value 3">Value 3</option>     
            </select>

               <script>
                   $(".js-example-placeholder-multiple").select2({
                       placeholder: "Search here",
                   });
               </script>

       <div class="form-inline justify-content-center">
           <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-xlarge">Search</button>
       </div>
   </form>
```

**views.py**

```
def search(request):
        search_query = request.GET.get('query', None)
        page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

        # Search
        if search_query:
            search_results = TestPage.objects.live().search(search_query)
            query = Query.get(search_query)

            # Record hit
            query.add_hit()
        else:
            search_results = TestPage.objects.none()

        # Pagination
        paginator = Paginator(search_results, 3)
        try:
            search_results = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            search_results = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            search_results = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        return render(request, 'search/search.html', {
            'search_query': search_query,
            'search_results': search_results,
        })
```

Comment: `getlist` is what you what, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's suggestions, they did help me but the solution I worked out below is the most helpful answer for anyone reading this question. The code below works perfectly for my requirements and allows for multiple values to be searched.

I was able to use the getlist method and then the functools module (used for higher-order functions) with reduce. The operator allows for `and` or `or`, I'm using currently using `and` which shows users results that only match all search values.

Took a while to get here, hope this helps others!

## Views.py

```
def search(request):
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    search_query = request.GET.getlist('query' , None)

    # searches for results that match all values
    query = functools.reduce(operator.and_, (Q(test_body__contains = i) for i in search_query))

    search_results = TestPage.objects.filter(query).distinct().order_by('-latest_revision_created_at')
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the `getlist()` method of the `GET` attribute.

for example:
`search_query = request.GET.get('query', None)`

should be

`search_query = request.GET.getlist('query', None)`

You can then loop through all of the search queries as such:

`for query in search_query:`

You can then use `Q Objects` for more complex queries:

```
q = Q()
for query in search_query:
    q |= Q(term=query)
ModelToQuery.objects.filter(q)
```

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist
>
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: Thanks Hybrid, I've tried your suggestion but I'm getting an Attribute Error "'list' object has no attribute 'lower'". Would it be possible to expand your answer for me?

Comment: That shouldnt be happening to you unless you are calling .lower() or .split() on the returned list

Comment: Still having problems. I've worked out that my multi-value query will work by simply replacing the & with a +. Is there a simple way to do this by updating my code?